# SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 while executing a python script that is encrypted with a password

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python script and I encrypted it with a password(using vim) so that no one can view the source code and trying to run the script on a remote server from Jenkins.

While executing the command:

```
python deploy.sh
```

I got the below error

```
SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xe0' in file deploy.py on line 1, but no encoding declared
```

I did add the line `# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-`

The question is what is the correct way to run the python script that has a password or a better way to encrypt the script so my source code is hidden. 
Again, I`m NOT trying to open the file, just execute the python script.

Any suggestions, please advise.

Comment: "Encrypted it with a password (using vim)"? Eh? Python can't execute code that's encrypted; it needs the actual source, not cyphertext that only becomes that source after decryption. You can't run a compiled executable after you encrypt it (and have something that's cyphertext instead of valid CPU instructions) either; same principle applies.

Comment: ...anyhow, if you want to argue that it should be possible, you're going to need to document the precise mechanism you're using that claims to generate an encrypted-but-executable script. (That said, I promise you that whatever encryption it uses, it's going to be trivial to reverse by anyone who has the ability to actually run the script in practice).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in python. If you want to write something in python and not have your seen by your users, you can't distribute the code. 
You could make it a service or webapp and host it on a server.

Or you could try compiling it ... https://medium.com/@xpl/protecting-python-sources-using-cython-dcd940bb188e